# How to fetch parent record based of existing children

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I would like to retrieve parent records by a existing children.

For instance I have:

**Parent Table : Meal**

```
ID  Meal
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

**Child Table: Ingredients**

```
ID MealID  Ingredient
1  1         x
2  1         y
3  1         z
4  2         x
5  2         y
6  3         x
```

I want to retrieve all Meals that have Ingredients x and y. Query should return Meal A and B.
I don't want to use any function like listagg or xmlagg to have all children names in a column and later use LIKE.

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select mealid
from ingredients
where ingredient in ('x', 'y')
group by mealid
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that ingredients are not repeated within a meal.  If they can be, you want `count(distinct ingredient) = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

*You can use :*

```
select m.meal
  from Meal m
  join Ingredients i on i.mealid = m.id
 where i.Ingredient in ('x','y') --
 group by m.meal                 --| => These two rows guarantees exactly returning of two rows with ingr. x & y
 having count(*)>1; ---------------

 MEAL
 -----
 A
 B
```

**Edit**(*depending on your last comment*)**:**

*You can retrieve all records from child where they have **both** ingredients **X** and **Y** by using **exists** as below :*

```
 select i.ID
   from Ingredients i
  where exists ( select 1 
                   from Ingredients
                  where MealID = i.MealID
                    and i.Ingredient in ('x','y') 
                  group by MealID    
                 having count(*)>1 
                );

ID
--
1
2
4
5
```

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/JQJXI33627)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Barbaros, this works. Looking into the records, I realize I don't need to use the parent, since all records are coming like the child table.

Do you have an idea how I can retrieve all records from child where they have ingredients X and Y. I need to retrieve all columns, including the ingredient name. The result should be all columns from records : 1,2,4,5 from child table.